# Perl - Use of uninitialized value?

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments

So I'm trying to run this code...

```
my $filePath = $ARGV['0'];
if ($filePath eq ""){
    print "Missing argument!";
}
```

It should check the first command line argument, and tell me if its empty, but it returns this error and I can not figure out why:

```
Use of uninitialized value $filePath in string eq at program.pl line 19.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what's with `'` around the array index?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just check to see if $ARGV[0] is defined

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

if(!defined $ARGV[0]){
    print "No FilePath Specified!\n";
}
```

This will print "No FilePath Specified!\n" if there was none passed command line.

The problem you are running into, is you are setting $filePath to an undefined value. Warnings is complaining because you've then tried to compare an undefined value to "". Warnings thinks that is worth telling you about.

I used my example to show a clean way of checking if something is defined, but technically for this, you could also just do:

```
if(!@ARGV){
    print "No FilePath Specified!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Empty and uninitialized are not the same thing. You can check if a variable is initialized with the `defined` operator, like for example:

```
if ((!defined $filePath) || ($filePath eq "")) {
 # $filePath is either not initialized, or initialized but empty
 ...
}
```

I'm pretty sure you meant this:

```
my $filePath = $ARGV[0];
```

(without the quotes)

Comment: The '||' option is not 100% the same. It will treat the perfectly-legal filename "0" as missing and provide the default instead.

Comment: I like: `if ( ! defined $filePath || ! length $filePath )`

Answer (score 4):

Alternative answer is to set a default value if it is not defined:

```
my $filePath = $ARGV[0] // '';
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As @Andrew pointed out, that's not same, as it will fail with filename "0"

Also, instead of

> if ((!defined $filePath) || ($filePath eq "")) { ...

as @Mat wrote. you can use simpler

> if(!$filePath) { ...

which does exactly the same

Comment: Not 100% the same. That will treat the perfectly-legal filename "0" as false.